# Facetime audio call contact via Siri

Tags: siri, facetime, call

I want to use facetime audio to call a contact via Siri, so I say "Call Contactname".
However the contact is called via regular phone call. Is it possible to change the functionality of "Call *" in order to have it do a facetime audio call instead of regular phone call?

Comment: Have you tried "Hey Siri - FaceTime call <contact_name>..."?

Comment: "Facetime *" starts a video call. 
However I wish to say "Call *" and start a facetime audio call instead of regular phone call. I do not want to say "facetime audio call *" or anything more complicated than simply call. Otherwise the whole thing loses its purpose.